# Oracle sql : get only specific part of a substring

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I'm struggling with a query in Oracle SQL, wanting to get some timings out of some text stored in an Oracle db.

```
Table :
kde_test (myString varchar(50))

Table contents (3 records):  
'task1 - 6m'
'task2 - 66m' 
'task3 - 666m'
```

I would like to get only the interesting part of the string, being the timings, so I would like to get only '6', '66' & '666' as results.

Searched this forum a bit, and got up with this query eventually, but it seems I do not completely get it, as the results it returns are : 
6m
66m
666m

```
select
CASE
WHEN myString like 'task1%' THEN substr(myString,9,INSTR(myString,'m',1,1)-1)
WHEN myString like 'task2%' THEN substr(myString,9,INSTR(myString,'m',1,1)-1)
WHEN myString like 'task3%' THEN substr(myString,9,INSTR(myString,'m',1,1)-1)
END
from kde_test
where myString like 'task%'
```

EDIT :

Since some solutions (thanks already for quick response) take into account the specific values (eg. all 3 records ending on '6m'), maybe it best to take into account the values could be :

```
Table contents (3 records):  
'task1 - 6m'
'task2 - 58m' 
'task3 - 123m'
```

Comment: It looks like this can be simplified to finding the character string between the second occurrence of a space and the last but one, non-inclusive.

Comment: No problem, you could simply use SUBSTR and INSTR and make it dynamic. See the edited answer with your edited values.

Answer (score 2):

Use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR** and make it dynamic.

```
SUBSTR(str, 
       instr(str, ' - ', 1, 1) +3, 
       instr(str, 'm', 1, 1) - 
       instr(str, ' - ', 1, 1) -3
      )
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'task1 - 6m' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'task2 - 66m' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'task3 - 666m' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'task4 - 58m' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'task5 - 123m' str FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT str,
  9    SUBSTR(str, instr(str, ' - ', 1, 1) +3,
 10                instr(str, 'm', 1, 1) - instr(str, ' - ', 1, 1) -3) new_st
 11  FROM DATA;

STR          NEW_STR
------------ ------------
task1 - 6m   6
task2 - 66m  66
task3 - 666m 666
task4 - 58m  58
task5 - 123m 123

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this way too

```
    select regexp_replace(SUBSTR('task3 - 666m' ,
    INSTR('task3 - 666m', '-',1, 1)+1, length('task3 - 666m')), '[A-Za-z]') 
   from  dual


result :666
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `regex_substr` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm#SQLRF06303).  `\d+` means one or more digits, and `$` anchors the end of the string.

```
select  regexp_substr(str, '\d+m$')
from    mytable
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4ef6/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

In order to correct your current query, you should change the following string - "INSTR(myString,'m',1,1)-1" to "INSTR(myString,'m',1,1)-9".
However, the other answers provided above seem like a more elegant solution to your problem.

I did feel the need to publish this just to clarify what wasn't working well in current query - in INSTR function returns the position of the m letter, and then used as the length of the string to print. What my fix does is telling the query to print everything from the 9th character until the position of the m letter, which results in the task time required.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to divide this into two parts

1. First pick the string after `-`

   ```
     regexp_substr ('task1 - 1234m', '[^ _ ]+',1, 3) --results 1234m
   ```
2. Fetch the number part of the string fetched from output of first

   ```
    regexp_substr(regexp_substr ('task1 - 1234m', '[^ _ ]+',1, 3),'[[:digit:]]*') 
    --output 1234
   ```

So,the final query is

```
 SELECT regexp_substr(regexp_substr (mystring, '[^ _ ]+',1, 3),'[[:digit:]]*')
 FROM kde_test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This:-

```
select substr(replace(myString,'m',''),9) output
from kde_test
where myString like 'task%'
```